# why my flutter function isn't working properly?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Can u check my widget code and tell me what's wrong the in the _saveForm function?? Bcuz, whenever i'm adding a new product in my list and saving it, it's not getting saved in my user products screen. I'm adding the codes from every widget related to this function. I'm not getting any error messages. But the _saveForm isn't saving the new items. I'm adding the updateProduct function and addProduct function code too which is related to the _saveForm function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/products_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/edit-product';

  @override
  State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    price: 0,
    imageUrl: '',
  );
  var _isInit = true;
  var _initValues = {
    'id': '',
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlController.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedProduct = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .findById(productId);
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
      _isInit = false;
    }
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (_imageUrlController.text.isEmpty ||
        (!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
            !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
        (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png') &&
            !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') &&
            !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg'))) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _editedProduct = Product(
        title: _editedProduct.title,
        description: _editedProduct.description,
        price: _editedProduct.price,
        imageUrl: _imageUrlController.text,
        id: _editedProduct.id,
        isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
      );
    });
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false).addProduct(
        Product(
          title: _editedProduct.title,
          description: _editedProduct.description,
          price: _editedProduct.price,
          imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          id: DateTime.now().toString(),
        ),
      );
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit Product'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _saveForm();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    title: value!,
                    description: _editedProduct.description,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a title.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    description: _editedProduct.description,
                    price: double.parse(value!),
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a price';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid number';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'Please enter a number greater than zero';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                maxLines: 3,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    description: value!,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a description';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Should be at least 10 characters long';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 6,
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? const Text(
                            'Enter a URL',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          )
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(
                              _imageUrlController.text,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          imageUrl: value!,
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                        );
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please provide an image URL';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

addProduct function

```
void addProduct(Product product) {
  final newProduct = Product(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    title: product.title,
    description: product.description,
    price: product.price,
    imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
  );
  _items.add(newProduct);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

updateProduct function

```
void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
  }
```

products_provider.dart codes for your review

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import './product.dart';

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  void addProduct(Product product) {
  final newProduct = Product(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    title: product.title,
    description: product.description,
    price: product.price,
    imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
  );
  _items.add(newProduct);
  notifyListeners();
}

  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
  }

  void deleteProduct(String id) {
    _items.removeWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

product.dart

```dart
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final double price;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have in the files`product.dart` and `products_provider.dart`?

Comment: Hi, check my widgets again please. I've added the other two widgets that u have requested to see. Thanks

Comment: Where do you have the code for `Provider`?

Comment: products_provider.dart is above for seeing

Answer (score 0):

`if (_editedProduct.id != null) {` logic is invalid because id will never be null.

```dart
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
```

And your `_editProduct`

```
  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
```

You can do

```
_form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedProduct.id.isEmpty) {
```

But better will be making nullable as you've been wise to use:

```
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String? id;
 ....
  Product({
    this.id,
```

Now you don't have to provide value on id, it is optional and can do null check.

Comment: Hi, none of the above solution worked.

Comment: what do you get while doing `_editedProduct.id.isEmpty`